# not getting property in the jsp page --getServletContext().getAttribute("rebrandchanges")))

Tags: java, spring, servlets, properties

CS.properties

```
APPLY_REBRAND_CHANGES = Y
```

ClmSrConstant.java

```
/** The Constant REBRAND_CHANGES. */
    public static final String REBRAND_CHANGES = "rebrandchanges";
```

InitServlet.java

```
package com.clmsr.controller;

import static com.clmsr.common.constant.ClmSrConstant.PROP_QUERIES;
import static com.clmsr.common.constant.ClmSrConstant.PROP_QUERIES_FILE;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

import com.clmsr.common.cache.DatabaseConnect;
import com.clmsr.common.cache.PropertiesCache;
import com.clmsr.common.constant.ClmSrConstant;
import com.clmsr.common.constant.ClmSrDebugConstant;

// TODO: Auto-generated Javadoc

public class InitServlet extends HttpServlet {

    /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3741423603997827839L;

    /** The Constant m_objlogger. */
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(InitServlet.class);
    
    @Value("${APPLY_REBRAND_CHANGES}")
    private String m_sApplyRebrandChanges;

    /**
     * init() method is invoked when the servlet instance is loaded.
     * 
     * @author CNSITDC
     * @version 1.0
     * @throws ServletException
     *             the ServletException
     */
    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig p_objConfig) throws ServletException {
        super.init();
        **p_objConfig.getServletContext().setAttribute(ClmSrConstant.REBRAND_CHANGES, m_sApplyRebrandChanges);**
        try {
            if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOGGER.debug(ClmSrDebugConstant.METHOD_INIT);
                LOGGER.debug(ClmSrDebugConstant.INITIALIZING_DB_AND_RENGINE);
            }
            PropertiesCache.addPropsFile(PROP_QUERIES, PROP_QUERIES_FILE);
            DatabaseConnect.setDataConnect();
        } catch (Exception exExp) {
            if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOGGER.error(ClmSrDebugConstant.EXCEP_INIT, exExp);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

pgHome.jsp

```
<%if("Y".equals((String)request.getServletContext().getAttribute("rebrandchanges"))){ %>
    <link href="assets/css/custom-overwrite-new.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/custom-theme-default-new.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <%} else { %>
    <link href="assets/css/custom-overwrite.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/custom-theme-default.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <% } %>
```

I am applying Y to the properties but unable to get it through the initservlet file. Please let me know where i am going wrong in this flow.